# ranked 2nd out of 124 peers -- Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, concept

I want to say that I ranked 2nd among all the students with the same entrance as mine at my university. I want to say this with as few words as possible. This the best I've been able to come up with:
ranked 2nd out of 124 peers

I would appreciate any suggestions that you might have.

Comment: ranked 2nd among all. 2 words fewer.

Comment: Peers to me suggests people within the same group as you, which could potential be at odds with "all students" e.g. if you're in the final year of a STEM course, would you count first year humanities students as peers? I'd simple drop the peers — *"Ranked second out of 124"*, or if appropriate, work out your rank as a percentile

Comment: @anotherdave, As you said, I don't want to convey "among all students". Just the students with the same entrance year at the university. Would "Ranked second out of 124" indirectly convey the meaning "among my peers"?

Comment: @Ali, comes down to context I think — for me, I think that would be the natural reading if it was written on your CV beside that year's exams results, for example

Comment: In U.S. English, the expression I'm most familiar with is "ranked second in a class of 124." The implied word _students_ at the end of the sentence is commonly left unspoken in this usage.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thanks! that was a really good suggestion

Comment: I suggest you eliminate the word "out":   "ranked second of 124 peers." Don

Answer (score -4):

At soccer, I ranked second *among* my peers.

Two things to keep in mind. "2nd" is not acceptable, in written form, in anything but the day of month. You also don't have to mention how many people were in the group, unless the number is somehow important to the reader, otherwise it just sounds like boasting.

Comment: Thanks @unmircea. The number 124 is really important in my situation! Any suggestions on how to include it?

Comment: "Ranked second in my class of 124."  I agree that the number 124 is important -- more impressive than if it were 20; less impressive than if it were 500.  And this is on an application or resume, where you need to impress, correct?  Another thought:  did you graduate second in your class?  If so, say "graduated second In my class of 124."

Comment: @ab2 Does "class" in this context imply "all undergraduate students of the same entrance year"? If yes, then I guess "Ranked second in my class of 124 " is a really good choice for me.

Comment: @ali When were you ranked?  When you entered or when you graduated? Class usually refers to the year one graduated for example "I was in the Class of 2004" means I graduated in 2004"  If you were somehow ranked when you entered (this seems odd to me, but not impossible), then you might say "ranked second in my matriculating class of 124."  I'm beginning to feel out of my depth, because I think you are talking about nuances in India (?)  that I don't understand.

Comment: :) No, we were ranked when we graduated. I understood what you mean and I am going with "Ranked second in my class of 124 ". Thanks for the help.